# docker-ce cannot map ports - says port is in use (even when it isn't)

Tags: docker

I have a problem with docker-ce running on debian 10.

I previously had a perfectly working install of Home Assistant with many addons - many of which require external networking. As part of a cleanup, I removed the old dockerd implementation of docker and did a clean install of docker-ce following the instructions on the docker website. Now, any addon that requires ports to be mapped fails to run.

To remove HA from the problem space, I ran

```
sudo docker run -p 12334:12334 hello-world
```

and got back

```
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint clever_mestorf (6e9826804c2719b01e3ef9a2f1f8619a09dc81f7a020c3e9bfed926add32c731): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp [::]:12334: bind: address already in use.
```

Obviously, port 12334 is not in use.

Comment: What steps did you take the verify the port is not in use?

Comment: `lsof -i :12334`

`ss -ltp`